# Fancyhdr - Why do changes in headheight influence the footer as well as the headheight in different pagestyles?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm a bit confused with the behaviour of fancyhdr.

1. When I change the `\headheight` for a `\fancypagestyle` to include a picture (here a tikz placeholder), why is the footer as well as the bottom margin not respected, but also moved (see first page of output)? How can I fix that?
2. Why does the `\headheight` of the first page with one `\fancypagestyle` seemingly influence the `headheight` of the second page with a different `\fancypagestyle` and different `\headheight` (see second page of output)?

A MWE and its output follows. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


%header first page
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
\setlength{\headheight}{130pt}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,5);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%main header
\fancypagestyle{main}{
\setlength{\headheight}{10pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Test Left}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{Test Right}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}

\pagestyle{main}


%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image: Page one, footer not respected (see arrow).]

[image: Page two, seemingly same headheight, but different fancypagestyle (see arrow).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the geometry set by the class, you must leave a vertical space on the first page, to make place for the expanded heading, and activate the `\pagestyle{main}` to start from the second page onwards.

[image: out2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{showframe} % added

%header first page
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
%\setlength{\headheight}{130pt} % not needed, will add unnecessary vspace
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,5);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \fancyhead[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%main header
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \setlength{\headheight}{20pt} %changed
    \fancyhead[L]{Test Left}
    \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{Test Right}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}

%\pagestyle{main}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{120pt}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

1.8.    \lipsum[1-8]

\pagestyle{main}

10. \lipsum
\end{document}
```

As an alternative, if you  want to control the geometry of all pages and only insert the figure in the first page:

[image: alt]

can be done using `geometry`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[top=30pt,bottom=30pt,left=80pt,right=80pt,includeheadfoot, headheight=2ex, headsep=20pt]{geometry}   %added

\usepackage{showframe}  %added
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}    %added

    %main header
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \setlength{\headheight}{2ex} % changed
    \fancyhead[L]{Test Left}
    \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{Test Right}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}    

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-45pt} 
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

1.8.    \lipsum[1-8]

\pagestyle{main}

10. \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, helps a lot! You're absolutely right: if only an image is inserted and if this happens only at the first page, there is no need for actually defining a fancypagestyle.